# How do I set padding in Highstocks's Xaxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I have a demant ! As shown in the figure , I try to set "maxPadding" in xAxis(highstocks's object properties) , but I find that can't , because you can't do it in the highstocks , just in highcharts ~~~ 
Can you help me ? Thank you

[image]

How do you make something like this picture ? what properties can I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xAxis.overscroll` which add an additional range on the right side of the xAxis. Note, that value is set in milliseconds separately for `chart.xAxis` and `naviagtor.xAxis`.

Code:

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },
  xAxis: {
   overscroll: 500000000
  },
  navigator: {
    xAxis: {
      overscroll: 500000000
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: [
      [1539264600000, 214.45],
      [1539351000000, 222.11],
      [1539610200000, 217.36],
      [1539696600000, 222.15],
      [1539783000000, 221.19],
      [1539869400000, 216.02],
      [1539955800000, 219.31],
      [1540215000000, 220.65],
      [1540301400000, 222.73],
      [1540387800000, 215.09],
      [1540474200000, 219.8],
      [1540560600000, 216.3],
      [1540819800000, 212.24],
      [1540906200000, 213.3],
      [1540992600000, 218.86],
      [1541079000000, 222.22],
      [1541165400000, 207.48],
      [1541428200000, 201.59],
      [1541514600000, 203.77],
      [1541601000000, 209.95],
      [1541687400000, 208.49],
      [1541773800000, 204.47],
      [1542033000000, 194.17],
      [1542119400000, 192.23],
      [1542205800000, 186.8]
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9qgs1L6w/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.overscroll

Comment: Thank you , it solve the problem for the view , but How to synchronize the data with the view?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Could you be more precise?

Comment: ok, I want my x axis also 'padding right', Because now only the view is 'padding right' , but x axis it doesn't.

Comment: So you don't want labels on the x-axis where the chart has empty space?

Comment: I want the x-axis also space , like views . So that the X-axis corresponds to the Y-axis .

Comment: You can make it with `xAxis.tickPositioner` remove ticks that have a value greater than data max value (API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner). Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/chLy2snr/.

Comment: Excuse me , I had a question ! How to modify tickPositioner's data dynamically .

Comment: You can use `Axis.update` method to provide tickPositions array with new values. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yd30g9nh/, API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update, https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions